# Does the position of an asterisk affect pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have noticed that in C++, a pointer can be declared using two different types of indentation (if that's the right word I'm looking for):

```
//Space followed by asterisk with variable name
char *pointer;

//Asterisk followed by space and then variable name
char* pointer;
```

Does the position of the asterisk affect anything about the pointer? If so, in what situations would I need to use one type of indentation over the other?

Comment: It is only a readability question.  The blank in either position is optional.  If you declare more than one variable together, the second way becomes seriously misleading: `char* pointer, notApointer;`  Personally, I strongly dislike declaring more than one variable together so I prefer `char* pointer;`

Comment: Since `char*` is not a token and `*pointer` is not a token, they must both be equivalent to these four tokens: `char`, `*`, `pointer`, `;`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No the whitespacing does not have any effect on the pointer declaration, but there is a bug in the C/C++ grammar (well, officially its a feature, but I don't know anyone who likes the behaviour), where this declaration

```
char* pointer, pointer2;
```

leaves `pointer` with the type of `char*` and `pointer2` with the type of `char`. Because of this, many people prefer to write it down as

```
char *pointer, *pointer2;
char *pointer, not_pointer;
```

to make it clearer, that the "pointerness" is part of the name, not type.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit this answer to reduce confusion. I hope I didn't spoil anything.

Comment: It's not a bug and it's even useful, I'll say, because it allows you to do: `int i = 10, *ptr = &i`. It works because pointers are _compound_ types: while you can have multiple compound types (ptrs, refs) in a declaration you can't have different types. Is it misleading, though? Yeah.

Answer (score 3):

No, the asterisk position has no effect on the declaration of a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the asterisk comes after the type and before the variable name, the spacing has no effect:

```
char *pointer;
```

Is the same as:

```
char      *             pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

In compound types like pointers, asterix (type modification) is part of a declarator. Actually declaration is formed of following ie.:

```
int i = 1, *pi = &i; 
^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ -- list of declarators 
 `- base type
```

in above i is an int, whie pi is a pointer

in:

```
int* p1, p2; // p1 is a pointer, while p2 is an int
int *p1, p2; // same as above
```